# Multi-line strings with quotes in R

Tags: r, string, whitespace, clipboard, quoting

I would like to select multiple lines of strings in R that contains internal quotation marks as a single object. However, I'd like to retain white spaces, line breaks and the double quotes `"` (and any single quotes `'`) inside the object.

So far, all of the string functions I've tried (e.g., `cat`, `quote`, `paste` `print`) do not work. Using a function like `writeClipboard` doesn't work either unless I wrap the code in `"` (double quotation marks).

- However, when I do this, the `"` inside of the strings I want to combine interfere with the wrapping `"`s.

Here's an example using writeClipboard (since this is my ultimate goal):

This doesn't work:

```
 writeClipboard(
   "
     x <- 1 + 2
     y <- "string" #I'm adding a random string surrounded by ""
     z <- function(x,y) {
            paste(x,y)
          }
     z(x,y)
   "
 )
```

This *does* work (but I am forced to change all of my `"` to `'`):

```
 writeClipboard(
   "
     x <- 1 + 2
     y <- 'string' #I'm adding a random string surrounded by ''
     z <- function(x,y) {
            paste(x,y)
          }
     z(x,y)
   "
 )
```

**Is there a way to "save" multiple lines of strings contianing white spaces, line breaks, and mixed `'` and `"` characters into a single string?**

- Again, I am primarily interested in doing so for `writeClipboard()`, but a more general answer would be appreciated as well!

Thanks!

Comment: Try escaping double quotes like this: `foo <- "this is a double quote \" inside double quotes" ; cat(foo)`

Comment: true that works, but I guess I'm trying to do this with 100s of lines of code, so going through and changing all the double quotes is not ideal (i.e., I would have to recopy all of my code and replace all the `"` with `\"` in this 2nd copy) -- this is more time consuming, and "messy" than I would like. Is there a way to do this with code as it's already written? For example, if I already have 100 lines of code, but now want to just wrap it in a string copying/compiling function)

Comment: Look into Regex for preprocessing, or the `stringr` package

Comment: It is still unclear how you're going to specify the argument of `writeClipboard()`: if you're already copy-pasting it, well, I guess you don't need `writeClipboard()` in the first place. If those "100 lines of code" are part of a script file, say, `my-script.R`, then maybe `writeClipboard(readr::read_file("my-script.R"))`?

Comment: I'm doing this in a knitr/r markdown interactive shiny doc in which I show a shiny app and its underlying code, but I want to provide a "copy code" button before the code for those that want to quickly copy code to an external R session. (vs drag/copy&paste)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the `deparse(quote(...))` pattern (the ugly `paste(head(tail(...` wrapper is for getting rid of the extra curly braces):

```
code_ <- paste(head(tail(deparse(quote({
  x <- 1 + 2
  y <- "string" #I'm adding a random string surrounded by ""
  z <- function(x,y) {
    paste(x,y)
  }
  z(x,y)
})), - 1), - 1), collapse = "\n")

cat(code_)

#     x <- 1 + 2
#     y <- "string"
#     z <- function(x, y) {
#         paste(x, y)
#     }
#     z(x, y)

print(code_)

# [1] "    x <- 1 + 2\n    y <- \"string\"\n    z <- function(x, y) {\n        paste(x, y)\n    }\n    z(x, y)"

writeClipboard(code_)
```